# How do I get the navbar to close when I click on a nav button?

Tags: html, css

When I click on a nav button, my navbar stays open. I'm really new to coding and would appreciate some guidance! I can get the hamburger button to open and close just fine. but when I click on a link to navigate through the website the navbar stays opened after I click on one.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.nav {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    /* position: relative; */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}

.nav > .nav-header {
  display: inline;
}

.nav > .nav-header > .nav-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.nav > .nav-btn {
  display: none;

}

.nav > .nav-links {
  display: inline;
  /* float: right; */
  font-size: 18px;
}

.nav > .nav-links > a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 13px 10px 13px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #efefef;
}

.nav > .nav-links > a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.nav > #nav-check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:700px) {
  .nav > .nav-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 13px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label:hover,.nav  #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-btn > label {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label > span {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #eee;
  }
  .nav > .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .nav > .nav-links > a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav > #nav-check:not(:checked) ~ .nav-links {
    height: 0px;
  }
  .nav > #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-links {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">

    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
    
    <div class="nav-header">
      <div class="nav-title">
        Gallegos Landscaping
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nav-btn">
      <label for="nav-check">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-links">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#about1">About</a>
      <a href="#services1">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: it's weird that the links in navigation are opening new tabs.

Comment: Post your js / css that operates your menu

Comment: yeah, that's an issue I fixed earlier today. I was following a tutorial and the guy added the target attribute "_blank". I fixed it but haven't pushed any updates

Comment: there's no javascript. this is just pure HTML and CSS.

Comment: You got JS, `app.js` but it's 404 not found.

Comment: You could mean a few different things, and without more code or specifics, it's luck if you get a good answer. Remove the external link and make sure we can tell what you're asking here in this question.

Comment: that's weird because I don't see an app.js file in my folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as you are using a checkbox to control visibility which is actually smart and I haven't seen before but it's somewhat limited in this use case.

I think an easier more dynamic approach would be to add some simple JavaScript. You can add an `onClick` handler to the menu button that will show/hide the menu by adding CSS.

So for example:

```
// JS
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menuToggle');

menuToggle.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (window.getComputedStyle(menu).display === 'block') {
    menu.style.display = 'none';
  } else  {
    menu.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

That way you can be in more control of opening / closing the menu. Right now it's staying open as the checkbox is staying checked but not updating

Comment: thank you so much! it worked! i need to start investing more time in JS. Do you have any pointers for someone just starting?

Comment: I recommend not to read too much about frameworks and get an understanding of regular native JS / CSS. A great resource to use is W3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/

If you use that and just focus on HTML, CSS and JS you will build a solid foundation to tackle anything in the future then. 

Another tip is to separate your presentation and logic so for the example, you had here you are doing your logic in CSS not JS. For any kind of dynamic behaviour, you will usually be better off with JS. 

Most of all, just keep practicing and reading, you will keep learning new stuff forever

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible to achieve what you need by CSS alone. 
Thus I have added a jQuery solution.

What I have done here is to un-check the checkbox after you have click on the links. Thus this trigger the closure of the dropdown menu.

```js
$('.nav-links > a').on('click', ()=>{

  $('#nav-check').prop('checked', false);
  
});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.nav {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    /* position: relative; */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}

.nav > .nav-header {
  display: inline;
}

.nav > .nav-header > .nav-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.nav > .nav-btn {
  display: none;

}

.nav > .nav-links {
  display: inline;
  /* float: right; */
  font-size: 18px;
}

.nav > .nav-links > a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 13px 10px 13px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #efefef;
}

.nav > .nav-links > a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.nav > #nav-check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:1000px) {
  .nav > .nav-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 13px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label:hover,.nav  #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-btn > label {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label > span {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #eee;
  }
  .nav > .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .nav > .nav-links > a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav > #nav-check:not(:checked) ~ .nav-links {
    height: 0px;
  }
  .nav > #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-links {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">

    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
    
    <div class="nav-header">
      <div class="nav-title">
        Gallegos Landscaping
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nav-btn">
      <label for="nav-check">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-links">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#about1">About</a>
      <a href="#services1">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: i appreciate your input on my post! i tested your method and it worked amazingly!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will solve your issue.

I have added a small script to your code which will close the navbar on click of menu item.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.nav {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    /* position: relative; */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}

.nav > .nav-header {
  display: inline;
}

.nav > .nav-header > .nav-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.nav > .nav-btn {
  display: none;

}

.nav > .nav-links {
  display: inline;
  /* float: right; */
  font-size: 18px;
}

.nav > .nav-links > a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 13px 10px 13px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #efefef;
}

.nav > .nav-links > a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.nav > #nav-check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:700px) {
  .nav > .nav-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 13px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label:hover,.nav  #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-btn > label {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label > span {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #eee;
  }
  .nav > .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .nav > .nav-links > a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav > #nav-check:not(:checked) ~ .nav-links {
    height: 0px;
  }
  .nav > #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-links {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .menu-open .nav-links {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px) !important;
    overflow-y: auto;
}  
 .nav-links {
    height: 0 !important;
}
}
</style>
<div class="nav">

    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">

    <div class="nav-header">
      <div class="nav-title">
        Gallegos Landscaping
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-btn">
      <label for="nav-check">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-links">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#about1">About</a>
      <a href="#services1">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".nav-btn").click(function(){
    $("body").toggleClass("menu-open");
  });
  $(".nav-links a").click(function(){
    $("body").toggleClass("menu-open");
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```